# Python DataFrame: rename columns from another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large DataFrame (Output_Frame) with columns defined by a list of two strings:

```
output_frame.columns
Out[14]: 
MultiIndex([('@:M3WRLD', 'AS1GRO'),
            ('@:M3WRLD', 'AS1GRO'),
            ('@:AFM2M2', 'AS1GRO'),
            ('@:AFM2E2', 'AS1GRO'),
        ...
names=['Instrument', 'Field'], length=903)
```

I would like to rename these columns to a single string contained in another DataFrame (Key):

```
                                Name Series_Code Datatype_Code  
0  MSCI AC WORLD - CAL FY1 GROWTH SAL    @:M3WRLD        AS1GRO  
1  MSCI AC WORLD - FY2 YOY GROWTH SAL    @:M3WRLD        AS2GRO  
2  MSCI AC WORLD - FY3 YOY GROWTH SAL    @:M3WRLD        AS3GRO  
3  MSCI AC WORLD - CAL FY1 YOY GROWTH    @:M3WRLD        AF1GRO
```

To reiterate: the column names of Output_Frame are the frields 'Series_Code' and 'Datatype_Code' from the Key frame. I would like to rename the column names in Output_Frame according to the Name Variable from Key.

For instance the first column in Output_Frame is:

```
('@:M3WRLD', 'AS1GRO')
```

And I want it to become:

```
MSCI AC WORLD - CAL FY1 GROWTH SAL
```

The following synatx is incorrect but I believe the logic would work.

```
for col in output_frame.columns:
    for row in key.rows:
        if (key[row, 'Series_Code'] == col[0]) && (key[row, 'Datatype_Code'] == col[1]):
            output_frame.column(col) = key[row, 'Type']
```

I would be grateful for suggestions in fixing this syntax or for suggesting a better way of accomplishing this - one which doesn't involve iteration. 
I'm very much a novice in Python and pandas and very grateful for your help.

Comment: `df.rename(columns={'@:M3WRLD':df.loc[df['@:M3WRLD'].str.contains('@:M3WRLD')==True].tolist()[0])` your structure isn't very clear ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I edited the question to make it a bit clearer. Output_Frame contains 903 columns - they all need to be renamed.

Comment: can you print the top 5 rows and 5 columns of your data frame ? `print(df.iloc[:5,:5])` and post it here if IIUC, you need to replace your col name with its matching value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to change 2-level multiindex columns of dataframe `output_frame` to single level index columns where values are mapped to values in `key` dataframe. I would say it is a risky logic. You need to make sure every pair-items of multindex exist in `key` dataframe. However, it is doing able. Assume `key` dataframe is named `df_key`. You may do the following:

```
Sample `output_frame` bases on your provided `multiindex` columns

Instrument @:M3WRLD        @:AFM2M2 @:AFM2E2
Field        AS1GRO AS1GRO   AS1GRO   AS1GRO
0                70     81       74       48

df_key
Out[539]:
                                 Name Series_Code Datatype_Code
0  MSCI AC WORLD - CAL FY1 GROWTH SAL    @:M3WRLD        AS1GRO
1  MSCI AC WORLD - FY2 YOY GROWTH SAL    @:M3WRLD        AS2GRO
2  MSCI AC WORLD - FY3 YOY GROWTH SAL    @:M3WRLD        AS3GRO
3  MSCI AC WORLD - CAL FY1 YOY GROWTH    @:M3WRLD        AF1GRO

#======================================================================
#create a dictionary from `df_key`
d = df_key.set_index(['Series_Code', 'Datatype_Code']).Name.to_dict()

##or
d = {tuple(v): k for k, *v in zip(*map(df_key.get, df_key))}

Out[526]:
{('@:M3WRLD', 'AS1GRO'): 'MSCI AC WORLD - CAL FY1 GROWTH SAL',
 ('@:M3WRLD', 'AS2GRO'): 'MSCI AC WORLD - FY2 YOY GROWTH SAL',
 ('@:M3WRLD', 'AS3GRO'): 'MSCI AC WORLD - FY3 YOY GROWTH SAL',
 ('@:M3WRLD', 'AF1GRO'): 'MSCI AC WORLD - CAL FY1 YOY GROWTH'}

#Use map on `output_dataframe.columns` to flatten and change its values to values from dictionary created from `df_key`
output_frame.columns = output_frame.columns.map(lambda x:  
                                                d.get(tuple(x), f'{x[0]} - {x[1]}'))


Out[534]:
   MSCI AC WORLD - CAL FY1 GROWTH SAL  MSCI AC WORLD - CAL FY1 GROWTH SAL  \
0                                  70                                  81

   @:AFM2M2 - AS1GRO  @:AFM2E2 - AS1GRO
0                 74                 48
```

---

**Note**: as I say you must *make sure every pair-items of multindex exist in `key` dataframe*. Your sample `output_frame` has mutiindex `('@:AFM2M2', 'AS1GRO')` and `('@:AFM2E2', 'AS1GRO')`, but `df_key` doesn't have these combos. Therefore, I chose to flatten them to `@:AFM2M2 - AS1GRO` and  `@:AFM2E2 - AS1GRO` instead of assigning `NaN` or `NoNe` to their locations. Second, your sample `output_frame` has duplicated mutiindex columns, so the mapping also mapped to duplicated values.

Comment: Thanks man, it works (I think) - but I'll be damned if I understand why. In the full thing, every column-name-list does have a unique Name associated with it.